# JsonProperty not working while minification enabled

Tags: android, jackson, proguard, kotlin

I have the following class

```
class CodeRequest(@JsonProperty("phone") val phoneNumber: String)
```

When I send request (using retrofit) with an object of this class as body (while minification is not enabled) everything works and request will be send in this form `{"phone": "123"}`

But enabling minification with the following `proguard-rules.pro` will result in a `{"phoneNumber": "123"}` request body.

```
# Jackson
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.* class * { *; }
-keep @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** class * { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.** { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature,Exceptions,InnerClasses
-keep class * {
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.* *;
}
-keep class * { @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty *;}

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Jackson
-keepclassmembers class my.application.data.models.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class my.application.domain.network.rest.** { *; }
```

What's missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found solution a couple of minutes after posting the question.
The problem is not with `proguard` nor `jackson`, it's that Kotlin erases required data which are stored in `kotlin.Metadata`.
Adding the following rule to proguard fixed the issue:

```
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```