# Proguard/R8 is minifying @JsonProperty annotation names in Kotlin data class for Jackson

Tags: android, kotlin, jackson, retrofit2, proguard

I have some classes used for Retrofit2, and serialized by Jackson.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class GetUserRequest(
    @JsonProperty("user_id")
    var userId: String? = null
)
```

They work in debug builds, but when I do a release build with proguard or R8 minification enabled, it minifies the classes variables (as expected), but also whatever code is generated by @JsonProperty, causing the network request to be sent with json like { "a": "123" } instead of { "user_id": "123" }

I have included support for kotlin by jackson
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.9"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.6.0"

And I have some proguard rules that work for my java class model objects.

```
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
-keep class * {
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator *;
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty *;
}

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
```

What proguard rules do I need to add so that Proguard does not minify the json properties?

I don't want to just exclude everything in my models package.

Comment: Maybe something like:
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty *;
}

Comment: Isn't that already covered by my -keep class * { JsonProperty }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JsonProperty not working while minification enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44098227/jsonproperty-not-working-while-minification-enabled)

Comment: The proguard in my question already contains the answer to the linked question. Also the symptom experienced is different. The linked issue has the @JsonAnnotation property being ignored, whereas mine has the fields themselves being renamed.

Comment: Looks to me as the issue is that the annotation `@JsonProperty("user_id")` becomes an annotation on the constructor parameter for the `GetUserRequest` and _not_ an annotation on the generated `userId` field. How about changing the declaration of the class to have an explicit `userId` field with the `@JsonProperty("user_id")` annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same problem. Solved it like this in your example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties (ignoreUnknown = true)
class GetUserRequest (
     @field:JsonProperty ("user_id")
     var userId: String? = null
)
```

The annotations from Kotlin data classes like this don't go into java code because, as [sgjesse said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787233/proguard-r8-is-minifying-jsonproperty-annotation-names-in-kotlin-data-class-for#comment100151158_56787233) in comments, in your example the annotation is applied to a constructor parameter, not a field.

You can read more about `@field:Annotation` [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets).

**P.S:**

In my case, this was enough to serialize objects to JSON (to make a request). However, this didn't work in case of **deserialization**, when **receiving a response**.

All I needed to add were **default parameters** for all fields. But you already have it in your example, I'm just writing this for those who will face the same issue.